# Symfony database and triggers

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, triggers

I'm curently learning how to use symfony 2.8 and I was wondering if it was possible to set triggers for its database. I'm using doctrine to generate the DB and I would like to set triggers for my projects.

Thakns in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add triggers to any database. Whether it is a good idea to do so in case of a cms with existing structure, that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick ansxer, I should have asked my question better. Is it ok to set a trigger in a database created by doctrine?

Comment: Yest, it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of Symfony / Doctrine  is to work with with most common databases types (mysql,pgsql,msqlite,sqlite etc. ), and  becouse of  this all your database logic  should be independend from specific  database system features.

In simple words : you need to move things  like tiggers to phpcode.
In symfony thereis event system (you can connect your  code to  be fired up on specyfic database  evenl like  update delete  select etc. )

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql triggers has nothing to do with symfony or doctrine and its ok to do so, but one of the main advantages of using an orm like doctrine is to be database agnostic. To do what you want you can use doctrine [events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html)(lifecycle callbacks) and theoretically it should work on any db supported by doctrine.